# Sonarqube 5.5 and mariadb

Tags: sonarqube, mariadb, sonarqube-ops, sonarqube-5.5

We are trying to upgrade to lastest sonarqube 5.5. We have mariadb 10.1 (latest) and since now we had no problems with sonarqube.

Now, with the upgrade, sonarqube will not boot. It says:

Unsupported mysql version: 5.5. Minimal supported version is 5.6.

Is there any trick we can use to make "sonar think" we are using mysql 5.6?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could change the *MINIMAL_SUPPORTED_DB_VERSIONS* member in the Sonarqube's class https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/sonar-db/src/main/java/org/sonar/db/DatabaseChecker.java

```
  private static final Map<String, Version> MINIMAL_SUPPORTED_DB_VERSIONS = ImmutableMap.of(
    // MsSQL 2008 is 10.x
    // MsSQL 2012 is 11.x
    // MsSQL 2014 is 12.x
    // https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321185
    MsSql.ID, Version.create(10, 0, 0),
    MySql.ID, Version.create(5, 6, 0),
    Oracle.ID, Version.create(11, 0, 0),
    PostgreSql.ID, Version.create(8, 0, 0)
  );
```

And build the project again, but If they have that requirement it's possible that after the change not everything is going to work fine.

Comment: Yes, I understand the risk.

Comment: Obviously removal of support of mysql < 5.6 was done on purpose. The checks are not here to annoy you but to ensure a correct and stable behavior at runtime. Your hack must not be used in production environment.

Comment: What I don't understand is what this answer is downvoted.

Comment: I downvoted as you recommend to remove a sanity check. That may lead to potential side-effects at runtime. It's not a responsible advice, neither for users, neither for community supporting these users.

Comment: I did't recommend anything, I gave an aswer to a question, and warned that doing that Sonarqube might not work fine.

Comment: We are using this as a test, we are a small team and starting with sonarqube analysis. If we like it we will implement it properly, with mysql, but meanwhile (1 or 2 months) we would like to use our database. We can afford the risk of losing everything

Comment: So you should instead test the version 5.4, which is Mysql 5.5 compliant (for testings is is enough), or use the embedded db - Sonarqube is delivered with an H2 databased in it. Hacking the code, is ugly, error prone and will most likely gives you strange errors at runtime. If the check is here, it is for a good reason. If you hack and have problems, you will blame Sonarqube but the root of the problem would be you - not them.

Comment: MariaDB 10 is MySQL 5.6 compatible, so the negative arguments about removing a sanity check are invalid. The sanity check itself should be more intelligent, especially with MariaDB replacing MySQL as the default MySQL implementation on many distributions, e.g., the mentioned CentOS 7.

Comment: @SimonBrandhof-SonarSource, could you please comment on the fact that MariaDB 10 is MySQL 5.6 compatible? Do you have any reason to believe that it's going to cause problems? It looks more like a bug in the sonar detection code... I mean I would understand "we did not test it with MariaDB and therefore cannot provide any guarantees" but "The checks are not here to annoy you.." sounds a bit harsh given the declared MariaDB compatibility.

Comment: @PatrickBergner this is not completely true, MariaDB 10.x and MySQL 5.6 and beyond are not fully compatible to each other anymore. Take the different GTID and parallel replication implementations for example.

Comment: @SimonBrandhof-SonarSource could you elaborate on the MySQL 5.6 specific features being used?

Comment: @HartmutHolzgraefe the reasons are described at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sonarqube/GmbtZ_qf1ME/vCHk4sZVAwAJ

Comment: This answer is outdated, since the code in v7 has changed

Comment: The question is for version 5.5, not version 7.

Answer (score 0):

here is a bsdiff file.

you can Patch it with:

```
bspatch sonar-db-5.6.jar sonar-db-5.6.jar.new sonar-db-5.6.jar.patch
```

Replace it and it works!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1EExMdpLmiLR1JmVFQ3ZTVPTlU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It seems it is a bug in MariaDB. The jdbc driver seems to report the major number on connection.getMetaData().getDatabaseMinorVersion(), thus it is 5.5 instead of 5.6.

Also, when performing getDatabaseProductVersion(), it returns here:

5.5.5-10.1.17-MariaDB

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB is not supported by SonarQube - still in v7. Please see this here:

[SonarQube Requirements](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements)

The Solution to run SonarQube in combination with XAMPP is to change the database from MariaDB to MySQL. Here you'll find the steps for changing it:

https://gist.github.com/odan/c799417460470c3776ffa8adce57eece