# SonarQube cannot start with MariaDB 10

Tags: sonarqube, mariadb, sonarqube-ops

I installed MariaDB with yum in CentOS 7.

SonarQube throws this exception:

```
org.sonar.api.utils.MessageException: Unsupported mysql version: 5.5. Minimal supported version is 5.6.
```

When I reinstall MariaDB with version 10, SonarQube still throws the same exception.

How does SonarQube-5.5 detect the MySQL version?

The API of MariaDB 10 is compatible with MySQL 5.6 and CentOS 7 has replaced MySQL with MariaDB.

Why does it not support MariaDB 10?

Comment: I had the same issue with sonar-5.6. When I switched back to sonar-5.3, it connected successfully. So, it might really be a bug in 5.6 as said below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sonarqube 5.5 and mariadb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37026631/sonarqube-5-5-and-mariadb)

Answer (score 7):

MariaDB is not supported by SonarQube, see [requirements](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements).

Comment: i noticed the requirements, but API of mariadb10 is compatible with mysql 5.6,  i have supposed the detection should be OK.

Comment: Sounds like SonaQube should check MariaDB and update their detection code.

Comment: Can one of you confirm that this is still a problem in 2018?

Comment: Yes. it is still a problem in 2018. Using MariaDB 10.2.12 on RHEL7 : `2018.02.08 18:11:14 INFO  web[][o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
2018.02.08 18:11:14 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] Web server startup failed: Unsupported mysql version: 5.5. Minimal supported version is 5.6.`

Answer (score 0):

Like Nicolas said, MariaDB is not supported by SonarQube - still in v7.

The Solution to run SonarQube in combination with XAMPP is to change the database from MariaDB to MySQL. Here you'll find the steps for changing it:

https://gist.github.com/odan/c799417460470c3776ffa8adce57eece